# How to @Inject fastxml.jackson.ObjectMapper into JAX-RS Resource?

Tags: java, jackson, websphere, cdi

I'm trying to inject an instance of the ObjectMapper class into my JAX-RS Resource, but I am seeing this error,

```
[ERROR   ] Api type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper] is not found with the qualifiers 
Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]
for injection into Field Injection Point, field name :  mapper, Bean Owner : [PageMetaResource, Name:null, WebBeans Type:MANAGED, API Types:[com.lmig.pi.ado.meta.resources.PageMetaResource], Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Any,javax.enterprise.inject.Default]]
```

I have an empty beans.xml file in the WEB-INF directory,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

I'm wondering if my Application.getSingletons() method is causing the issue,

```
@Override
public Set<Object> getSingletons()
{
    Set<Object> set = new HashSet<>();

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT);
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS, false);
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    mapper.setDateFormat(df);

    JacksonJsonProvider provider = new JacksonJsonProvider();
    provider.setMapper(mapper);

    set.add(provider);

    return set;
}
```

My resource class looks like this,

```
public class PageMetaResource extends BasePresentationResource
{
    /**
     * The logger of the class
     */
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PageMetaResource.class);

    /**
     * Factory that produces a {@link PageMetaServices} instance for this resource.
     */
    private ServiceFactory serviceFactory;

    /**
     * Factory that produces a {@link PageMetaResourceBean} instance for this resource.
     */
    private ResourceBeanFactory resourceBeanFactory;

    /**
     * The servlet context.
     */
    @Context
    private ServletContext context;

    @Inject
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    @Inject
    public PageMetaResource(ServiceFactory serviceFactory, ResourceBeanFactory resourceBeanFactory)
    {
        this.serviceFactory = serviceFactory;        
        this.resourceBeanFactory = resourceBeanFactory;
    }
...
}
```

Any ideas?  I've tried to @inject into the constructor - but a similar error was thrown.

Thanks for the help,

Andrew

PS:  I am deploying to Websphere Application Server v8.5 Liberty Profile

Answer (score 0):

Your CDI-Container does not find a producer for `ObjectMapper`. Take a look [here](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#d0e960).

Comment: Just so it's clearer.  There is no "built in" producer for `ObjectMapper`, you must provide one yourself.

Comment: Actually if you include `jackson-jaxrs-json-provider` module (from https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers), it should be auto-registered. Although you may still want to be explicit to get custom configurations in.